# Download and resize image from url

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
echo 'curl: ', function_exists('curl_version') ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled';
echo ' - ';
echo 'file_get_contents: ', file_get_contents(__FILE__) ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled';

$img = file_get_contents('http://www.mundodeportivo.com/r/GODO/MD/p4/Barca/Imagenes/2017/03/08/Recortada/MUNDODEPORTIVO_G_4519253-ktyD-U42659987163F0E-980x554@MundoDeportivo-Web.jpg');

$im = imagecreatefromstring($img);

$width = imagesx($im);

$height = imagesy($im);

$newwidth = '120';

$newheight = '120';

$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);

imagecopyresized($thumb, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

imagejpeg($thumb,'aaa.jpg'); //save image as jpg

imagedestroy($thumb); 

imagedestroy($im);
```

**You can test here:**

http://aszx.altervista.org/saveimgfromurl/index.php

http://aszx.altervista.org/saveimgfromurl/aaa.jpg

Why does it not work ?

Comment: i tested your code it is working fine, what error you getting?

Comment: @Jabs as you can see ( http://aszx.altervista.org/saveimgfromurl/aaa.jpg ) the image saved is empty. Why ?

Comment: hmm, i am not sure but you can try on another server as on my end i can see resized surfing image

Comment: @Jabs Just tryed on another server, and it does work. But I would like to know why it doesn't work on this server :)

Comment: may be some image library/extension issue, to confirm you can compare versions on both servers

Comment: @bansi why do you think that the problem is that ?

Comment: @xRobot you are correct. It works as is in my end also. think i should take a break not seeing things properly...

Comment: Must be something wrong with retrieving the source image. Try to `file_put_contents(tempnam('/tmp', 'img_'), $img);` to confirm it is a valid one.